# Cronjob not enough time for php script?

Tags: php, cron

I use php to change some content of a csv.
It works so far if i call the script in a browser. But if i run it via a vronjob it will not write the whole file but only a small part of the csv.
So is it possible that cron has not enough time to do the whole job?

With this code i get the csv and change a few things in it:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(60);


$row = 0;
$fp = fopen('changed-stock.csv', 'w');
if (($handle = fopen("https://www.xxx.de/xxx/bestand.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 90000000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $data[9] = str_replace(['0.00', '1.00', '2.00', '3.00', '4.00', '5.00', '6.00', '7.00', '8.00', '9.00', '10.00', '11.00', '12.00', '13.00', '14.00', '15.00', '16.00', '17.00', '18.00', '19.00', '20.00'],
            ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20'], $data[9]);

        fputcsv($fp, $data);
    }
}
fclose($fp);

?>
```

In my old file for another project i have

```
...$handle, 90000000,...
```

with 20000 but i increased it to 90000000 because maybe it was not enough?

My Cron looks like this:

```
01 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q http://xxx.de/csvread/xx/change-stock.php
```

So if io cun this php in browser my new written csv is 628 KB and if the same script runs from cron it's only 133 KB.

The Cronlog shows no error.
I hope some one can help me.

Comment: If the cron job is on the same server, then just call the php file directly instead of running it through wget. Command line PHP does not have a timeout restriction that web browsers/curl/wget does.

Comment: Is it timing out? Is 90000000 sane? What is the longest line? At that point I'd just omit the argument. What does your PHP log show? Log your errors. Have no idea how your cronjob will capture that error output.

Comment: With `wget -q` you certainly won't see much useful in cron.log.

Comment: thanks for your answers.
i added the timelimit beacause i thought that it will tell the script to run at least 60 seconds. 
this 9000000 was before just 20000. so i increased it but with no effect. And the csv contains only about 5000 rows and 9 colums. and every cell has just a verry small value. so 20000 was actually enough.

@aynber:
i changed the cron to 


  `1 * * * * http://xxx.de/csvread/xx/change-stock.php

but then nothing happens.`

Comment: Change the url to /usr/bin/php /path/to/file/on/disk

Comment: i tried but nothing happens. But i changed the cron to
`1 * * * * curl http://xxx.de/csvread/xx/change-stock.php` and it seems to work